# Finding rate of change of f at p in direction of unit vector - finding unit vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I have f(x,y) = sin(2x+3Y) and a point P(-6, 4).

I found $\nabla f= \langle2cos(2x+3y), 3cos(2x+3y)\rangle$
and $\nabla f (-6, 4) = \langle2,3\rangle$.

The final part of the question with a final answer of $\sqrt{3}-\frac{3}{2}$, was to find the rate of change of f at p in the direction of the unit vector. I think I'm supposed to use $D_uf= \nabla f*u$ but I'm not sure how to find u here.

Comment: In the direction of which unit vector?  It should say somewhere in the problem statement.

Comment: Yea, didn't know the code, lol, only way I could think of. XD I see there's  way to show it from your comment so will fix in the post and note for later. And um... ok... How do I go about finding one of these infinitely many choices?

Comment: There's no way to find it -- it should be in the problem statement.

Comment: But it's not... it just asks that and then the answer is supposed to be $\sqrt{3} - 3/2$ somehow...

Comment: Well $u$ has to be $\langle \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\frac 12\rangle$ to get that answer, but that's the best I can say.  You could find the rate of change in whichever direction you like -- there's no reason I see why you should have chosen that one.

Comment: Hmm. Alright. Well then hopefully this particular weird book problem is the only one of it's sort I see then and it doesn't somehow wind up on a test.